# socket.getaddrinfo() block forever when using with gevent

Tags: python, sockets, gevent, httplib2, getaddrinfo

Using `httplib2`, I am sending multiple requests with `gevent`, after some time `http.request()` method of `httplib2` is getting blocked forever.
On checking I found that blocking function is `socket.getaddrinfo()` in httplib2 [link](https://github.com/jcgregorio/httplib2/blob/master/python2/httplib2/__init__.py#L1020).

Comment: [This open issue](https://github.com/surfly/gevent/issues/230) on gevent's issue tracker seems to be relevant to this.

Comment: actually, its not working, i tried that too...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

set default timeout using `socket.setdefaulttimeout()`. since timeout of getaddrinfo is not specified it will use default timeout.