# Socket.getaddrinfo gets stuck, blocking the process indefinitely when using requests in python

Tags: python, python-requests, blocking

here is simple demo of my project:

```
import requests
import json, time
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
def request(url, msg=None, timeout=2, method="get"):
    flag, resp = False, None
    try:
        if method == "get":
            resp = requests.get(url, params=msg, timeout=timeout, verify=False)
    elif method == "post":
        resp = requests.post(url, data=msg, timeout=timeout, verify=False)
    elif method == "delete":
        s=requests.Session()
        resp = s.delete(url, data=msg, timeout=timeout, verify=False)

    flag = True
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        resp = "time_out"
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        resp = "too_many_redirect"
    except requests.ConnectionError as err:
        resp = "connection_error"
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        resp = str(err.__class__.__name__)

    return flag, resp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        print request("https://www.google.com", timeout=1)
        time.sleep(1)
```

after running for a while the process will block, when i pstack i always saw this:

```
Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f465f310700 (LWP 22537)):
#0  0x00000030dd0e993d in recvmsg () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000030dd10f8d5 in make_request () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00000030dd10fd0a in __check_pf () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x00000030dd0d2ec7 in getaddrinfo () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f46647e07bf in socket_getaddrinfo () from ...
```

i have found a message [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883247/socket-getaddrinfo-block-forever-when-using-with-gevent) and known it was blocking when querying the DNS and i have set the timeout for the request,but it was useless! Does anybody ever meet this problem? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search with Google，I found this post [[Bug libc/12926] getaddrinfo()/make_request() may spin forever](http:///https://sourceware.org/ml/glibc-bugs/2015-05/msg00228.html) and the bug was fixed in [The GNU C Library version 2.23](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-02/msg00009.html). But it's impossible to update the glibc on my machine.

I used to write a python program that use the **requests** module too, it doesn't has this problem so i compared both of that carefully and i found the biggest difference is **the number of the thread which using the requests for http request. the first one has only one thread using requests but the last one has two** so i refactored the program as a single thread program for a test. The problem is never happened agin.

The [man page of requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) said that the requests is thread safe , i have not found the exactly reason of this bug so i just used a single-thread method to avoid this problem.

If some one know that any advice will be appreciated.